# Trying to get all content of directory from one server to another using ssh2_scp_recv in php

Tags: php, ssh2-exec, ssh2-sftp

The below script is working successfully.

Getting file from one server to another

```
if(ssh2_scp_recv($conn, '/var/www/html/captures/store/2016/04/HK/15721022890870/test/vcredist.bmp', 
    '/var/www/html/captures/store/2016/04/HK/15721022890870/test/vcredist.bmp')){
echo "\n recevied \n";
  }else{
 echo "\n not recevied\n";
  }
```

But instead for fetching just a static file, I want to fetch folder with all its content inside.

With above example, the directory I would like to fetch to local server is  "15721022890870"

```
/var/www/html/captures/store/2016/04/HK/15721022890870/
```

I have tried below code but doesn't work,

The remote server has directory, but the local server doesn't have, so I want to make directory then copy all its content inside

```
if(ssh2_scp_recv($conn, '/var/www/html/captures/store/2016/04/HK/15721022890870/', 
    '/var/www/html/captures/store/2016/04/HK/')){
echo "\n recevied done \n";
  }else{
  echo "\n not done \n";
   }
```

Comment: `ssh2_scp_recv` does not support multiple file copies. You might be successful with `ssh2_exec` and/or `ssh2_tunnel`, but just an unproved idea. What is your environment? Don't you have access to the system via `exec`? Generally, why are you using PHP?

Comment: All server is based on Ubuntu, Linux.  Yes, I have full access system via exec. The reason I am using PHP there is post-processing script before fetching content

Comment: So why don't you call `scp` via exec? When using key pair, no interaction is required.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$username = "your_username";
$password = "your_pass";
$url      = 'your_stp_server_url';
// Make our connection
$connection = ssh2_connect($url);

// Authenticate
if (!ssh2_auth_password($connection, $username, $password)) throw new Exception('Unable to connect.');

// Create our SFTP resource
if (!$sftp = ssh2_sftp($connection)) throw new Exception('Unable to create SFTP connection.');
$localDir  = '/path/to/your/local/dir';
$remoteDir = '/path/to/your/remote/dir';
// download all the files
$files    = scandir('ssh2.sftp://' . $sftp . $remoteDir);
if (!empty($files)) {
  foreach ($files as $file) {
    if ($file != '.' && $file != '..') {
      ssh2_scp_recv($connection, "$remoteDir/$file", "$localDir/$file");
    }
  }
}
?>
```

This is from server to computer but you can modify the $localDir